# Why $U(c,b)U(b,a)=U(c,a)$ instead of $\int_a^c db U(c,b)U(b,a)=U(c,a)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, time-evolution

It's supposed to be a hw&exercise but the proof was in the textbook, in the purpose that one study it. However, somehow the proof in the book was confusing and felt wrong.

Consider a time evolution operator or time ordered product,
$$U(b,a)=T\{\exp [-i \int_a^b dt H(t)]\}\tag{1}$$
where $T$ was the time ordering operator.

The statement was that, since

> $$i\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=H(t)U(t,t_0)\tag{2}$$
> ... using boundary condition $$U(t_0,t_0)=1\tag{3}$$ with
> $$i\frac{\partial U(t,t_0)U(t_0,t_2)}{\partial t}=H(t)U(t,t_0)U(t_0,t_2)\tag{4}$$
> and, thus, $$U(t,t_0)U(t_0,t_2)=U(t,t_2)\tag{5}$$

But $t_0$ here was assumed to be a fixed value, an assumption that was ignored during the computation, in the sense that not all the path in temporal domain were counted for $U(t,t_0)U(t_0,t_2).$
After doing the algebra for time ordered product directly,
$$\int_a^cdb (T\{\exp [-i \int_b^c dt H(t)]\} T\{\exp [-i \int_a^b dt H(t)]\})=T\{\exp [-i \int_a^c dt H(t)]\}\tag{6}$$
i.e.
$$\int_a^c db U(c,b)U(b,a)=U(c,a)\tag{7}$$

Why $U(c,b)U(b,a)=U(c,a)$ instead of $\int_a^c db U(c,b)U(b,a)=U(c,a)$?

Comment: Updates: $\int_a^cdb$ was wrong because there was actually a $\theta(t_1-b)$ function involved for $U(c,b)$. Thus the the "philosophy" translated into $\lim_{b\rightarrow a}U(c,b)U(b,a)$ the definition of $U(c,a)$. The $U(c,b)U(b,a)$ itself, however, the identity factors i.e. from the $1$ in the factors of $[1+\sum_{n=1}(c,b)(O)_n][1+\sum_{m=1}(b,a)(O)_m]$ followed fundamental theorem of calculus, and summed up to $U(c,a)$ which implied that the rest of the cross terms of $(c,b)(O)_n(a,b)(O)_m=...\int_b^{t_1}dt_1 O(t_1)   \int^b_{h_m}dh_mO(h_m)$ terms vanished after $\sum_{m,n}$ for $m,n\geq1$

Comment: It then made sense, the meaning of boundary condition was exactly stating the fact that $\int_a^b dx f(x)+\int_b^c dx f(x)=\int_a^c dx f(x)$, while the cross term vanish after the sum consistent with the idea of path integral formalism, i.e. the probably contribution of a "single path", through point $b$, was zero, since $\int_b^b f(x)dx=0$.(or maybe it had to do with something else, since it was proven indirectly through the result obtained from the boundary condition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially because the group property (5) not (7) meet the correct boundary condition (3).